# Assign/Extract values from list in data.table to columns

Tags: r, data.table

I somehow try to get my data out of a column list and assign it to different columns  - assuming the vectors in the list all have fixed length.

```
 require(data.table)

d <- data.table(id=1:3,l=list(c(1,2),c(5,6),c(7,9))) 
# d
#    id   l
# 1:  1 1,2
# 2:  2 5,6
# 3:  3 7,9


d[,':='(l1 = l[[1]][1],l2=l[[1]][2])]

# d
#    id   l l1 l2
# 1:  1 1,2  1  2
# 2:  2 5,6  1  2
# 3:  3 7,9  1  2

# EXPECTED
# d
#    id   l l1 l2
# 1:  1 1,2  1  2
# 2:  2 5,6  5  6
# 3:  3 7,9  7  9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `Map`

```
d[, paste0("l", 1:2) := do.call(Map, c(f = list, l))]
d
#   id   l l1 l2
#1:  1 1,2  1  2
#2:  2 5,6  5  6
#3:  3 7,9  7  9
```

If we need a `vector` as output, change `f=list` to `f=c`

```
d[, paste0("l", 1:2) := do.call(Map, c(f = c, l))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, apparently I have to force a rowwise treatment. In this case e.g. by ID:

```
 d[,':='(l1 = l[[1]][1],l2=l[[1]][2]),by=.(id)]
```